# How to find chaincode id in fabric?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

How to find chaincode id after running `peer chaincode  install` and `peer chaincode  instantiate` commands.

While running `peer chaincode query` I need to pass the chaincode id. Otherwise I am getting this error in peer console:

```
ChaincodeId: test_cc does not exist on channel: testchainid(err:chaincode not found test_cc)
```

Comment: I got similar error when I queried remote peer. I also posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301866/transaction-not-found-on-remote-peer

Comment: Let me know when you find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Usage:
peer chaincode install [flags]

Flags:
-h, --help   help for install

Global Flags:
  --cafile string              Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
  -C, --chainID string             The chain on which this command should be executed (default "testchainid")
  -c, --ctor string                Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
  -E, --escc string                The name of the endorsement system chaincode to be used for this chaincode
  -l, --lang string                Language the chaincode is written in (default "golang")
  --logging-level string       Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -n, --name string                Name of the chaincode
  -o, --orderer string             Ordering service endpoint
  -p, --path string                Path to chaincode
  -P, --policy string              The endorsement policy associated to this chaincode
  --test.coverprofile string   Done (default "coverage.cov")
  -t, --tid string                 Name of a custom ID generation algorithm (hashing and decoding) e.g. sha256base64
  --tls                        Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
  -u, --username string            Username for chaincode operations when security is enabled
  -v, --version string             Version of the chaincode specified in install/instantiate/upgrade commands
  -V, --vscc string                The name of the verification system chaincode to be used for this chaincode
```

the `-n` or `--name` option that you use is the chaincode id.